# IE - Invalid Argument jQuery error

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, invalid-argument

I'm getting the invalid argument error and can't figure out what's causing it.

Hoping someone could help me out.

The script stops running after this piece (probably) of code:

```
if (type == "all") {
    var classe = target.substring(1) + '-' + color + '-bottom';
    $(target).after('<div class="' + classe + ' block"></div>');
    $('.'+classe).css({
        'height' : colors[color].botHeight,
        'background-image': "url(" + url + colors[color].bot + ")",
        'background-repeat': 'repeat-x'
    }); 
    $('.'+classe).offset({left: 0});
    $('.'+classe).width($(window).width());
}
```

Full Script: http://www.mochilao.syncmobile.com.br/wp-content/themes/headway/custom.js
(sorry for the mess)

Answer (score 0):

are all of your variables declared? i see 5 variables used but only one is declared.

also, if "target" is a string (you are performing .substring on it) then it does not make much sense to wrap it in jQuery and call .after() on the next line.

i would suggest adding some debuggers or alerts and figure out where exactly your code is breaking.

Comment: All variables are declared. Target is a class passed as parameter, like ".class", so I use substring to cut the '.' to create a custom class for the div. Added the full script if it would help.

Comment: @GuilhermeVerri so that rules that out, were you able to add any debuggers or breakpoints and figure out exactly what function call is failing?

Comment: I couldn't. But I think the problem was with the script loaded from an iframe (used with a facebook plugin).